# lmfit for plotting parameters

Tags: python, lmfit

I am trying to do a sensitivity analysis of a simple chemical reaction system. A -> B (with reaction rate k1) and A1 -> B(k2), B-C (k3), C-> B (k4). The point is to plot rates. So if it is a small k1 value, there should be a large k2 value and if k3 and k4 should be equal. For k1 and k2 I get some sort of a trend, but k4 is always the same. What am I missing? Am I varying parameters wrong?

My attempt

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Parameters, report_fit, Minimizer, minimize, printfuncs, conf_interval, conf_interval2d
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from sys import exit
time = 10
Nt = 200
tt = np.linspace(0,time, Nt)   
p = Parameters()
# add with tuples: (NAME VALUE VARY MIN  MAX  EXPR  BRUTE_STEP)
p.add_many(('k1', 0.5, True, 0,1), ('k2', 0.5, True, 0,1), ('k3', 0.5, True, 0,1), ('k4', 0.5, True, 0,1))

time = 10
Nt = 11
tt = np.linspace(0,time, Nt)


def f(xs, t, ps):
    """Test"""
    try:
        k1 = ps['k1'].value
        k2 = ps['k2'].value
        k3 = ps['k3'].value
        k4 = ps['k4'].value
    except:
        k1, k2, k3, k4 = ps

    a, a1, b, c = xs
    da_dt = - k1*a
    da1_dt = - k2*a1
    db_dt = k1*a + k2*a1 + k4*c - k3*b
    dc_dt = k3*b - k4*c
    return da_dt, da1_dt, db_dt, dc_dt

def g(t, x0, ps):
    """
    Solution to the ODE x'(t) = f(t,x,k) with initial condition x(0) = x0
    """
    x = odeint(f, x0, t, args=(ps,))
    return x

def residual(ps, ts, data):
    x0 = np.array([1,0.5,0,0])
    model = g(ts, x0, ps)
    return (model)


#exit()
x0 = np.array([1,0.5,0,0])

k1, k2, k3, k4 = 1,1,1,1
true_params = np.array((k1,k2,k3,k4))
data = g(tt, x0, true_params)
data += ((np.random.normal(size=data.shape))) 

# create Minimizer
mini = Minimizer(residual, p,fcn_args=(tt,data))

# first solve with Nelder-Mead
out1 = mini.minimize(method='emcee')

out2 = mini.minimize(params=out1.params, method='Powell')

print(fit_report(out2))
print(report_fit(out1.params, min_correl=2))
##
ci, trace = conf_interval(mini, out2, sigmas = [0.01,0.02,0.3,0.4],
                                trace=True, verbose=True, maxiter = 200)


figure(1)
x, y, prob = trace['k1']['k1'], trace['k1']['k2'], trace['k1']['prob']
#x, y, prob = trace['k2']['k2'], trace['k2']['k1'], trace['k2']['prob']
scatter(x, y, c=prob ,s=30)
#plt.gca().set_xlim((0.00, 0.1))
#plt.gca().set_ylim((0.01, 0.1))
ylabel('k2')
xlabel('k1')
#plt.show()

figure(2)
x2, y2, prob2 = trace['k3']['k3'], trace['k3']['k4'],trace['k3']['prob']
x2, y2, prob2 = trace['k4']['k4'], trace['k4']['k3'],trace['k4']['prob']
scatter(x2, y2, s= 30, c= prob2)
#plt.gca().set_xlim((0, 0.1))
#plt.gca().set_ylim((0, 0.1))
xlabel('k3')
ylabel('k4')
```

Comment: There's way too much code (too many gears) here. How can you be sure that you're solving the ODE correctly? And are you sure your assumptions for the rate coefficients are correct? If you ask about fitting, only produce a fitting problem.

Comment: I was asking more about sensitivity analysis.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, `k3` and/or `k4` end up being at or at least very, very close to your upper bound of 1.0.  You should use bounds sparingly and be physically meaningful.   That is, the real "problem" is that you use `Parameters.add_many()` and set all parameters to be between `[0, 1]`.

In this sense, the fit did work and even did what you asked ;).   But if you relax those bounds, you'll probably get a better result.

FWIW, it is probably not necessary to first solve with Nelder-Mead and then with `leastsq` (and if you do want to do that, you should spell Nelder correctly0.

Comment: Yeah I solved it during the weekend. Thanks for your help! I saw that it is working kinda, but still i get weird results. Will keep trying.

Comment: Oh I get something like that. https://imgur.com/pd4JcRy What is the straight line there? It shouldnt be there? can you help?

Comment: Well, um, what is the code that produced the image you posted?  The idea here is to ask answerable questions about your code....

Comment: Its the code I posted in this post. But I found a work around I get some nice results hopefully.

Comment: Even here if I fit the code. By every logic if k3 would fall to 0.3, the k4 should be 0.3 as well, but here the case is not like that. Since at multiple occasions i get k3 = 0.7 and k4 is 0.8.